Qt enums/flags and QVariant::toString
Any value of type Qt::Alignment (flag) can be converted to a nice to read string, such as what is done below:
QString s = QVariant::fromValue<Qt::Alignment>(Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignLeft).toString();

That code fills s with AlignLeading|AlignTop.
That is correct in a way, as Qt::AlignLeading is a synonym for Qt::AlignLeft. I would rather get the original value than its synonym, though and apparently, the Qt team agrees as the Property editor of the Qt designer makes no mention of the synonyms.
Is there a way to get the string I want with Qt-only functionalities, i.e. without some sort of hack?

I don't think it would be possible: once an enum is OR-ed, it theoretically loses any original aspect of its definition, an the QVariant convertion fundamentally iterates through the enum based on its resulting value, without any knowledge of how it was constructed. It uses QMetaEnum::valueToKeys(), so you may check the sources to see how it's implemented.

That does not look true. It is possible to declare flags for which QVariant::toString returns an empty string and at the same time QMetaEnum::valueToKeys() returns the correct data.

Sorry about the confusion. I meant valueToKey() (see the qvariant.cpp code, it never uses the "keys" function). That's the reason for which it returns a null string: it only returns one known key for a defined enum, if it exists, so OR-ed enums will not be considered, unless defined (eg: Qt.AlignCenter). Yet, if the problem is displaying the value in an item view, the simplest solution would be to just override displayText() in a delegate.

You can register your own converter for Qt::Alignment somewhere on application startup (I hope this is not a hack you want to avoid). Here is some example
QMetaType::registerConverter<Qt::Alignment, QString>([](const Qt::Alignment &align) {
    static const QMap<Qt::Alignment, QString> alignMap {{Qt::AlignLeft, "AlignLeft"},
                                                          {Qt::AlignRight, "AlignRight"},
                                                          {Qt::AlignHCenter, "AlignHCenter"},
                                                          {Qt::AlignJustify, "AlignJustify"},
                                                          {Qt::AlignAbsolute, "AlignAbsolute"},
                                                          {Qt::AlignTop, "AlignTop"},
                                                          {Qt::AlignBottom, "AlignBottom"},
                                                          {Qt::AlignVCenter, "AlignVCenter"},
                                                          {Qt::AlignBaseline, "AlignBaseline"}};
    QString textResult;
    for (auto [alignKey, alignText] : alignMap.asKeyValueRange())
    {
        if (alignKey & align)
        {
            textResult.append(alignText);
            textResult.append("|");
        }
    }

    if (!textResult.isEmpty())
    {
        textResult.removeLast();
    }

    return textResult;
});


Very nice solution. What I called a hack was something that would either work around QVariant::toString or work only for that and would need to be repeated to make the text the same in several places. Your solution makes the customized text available in QVariant::toString, QStyledItemDelegate::displayText (nice rendering in models) and copy/paste from views (+ possibly other things I have yet to test). Apparently, it does not need to be registered on start-up, it can be done any time.

That's an interesting approach. You may also consider the case of just returning AlignCenter in case it's the only matching flag.

Well, a small number of things could be improved in the answer such as not using a reference as parameter (Qt::Alignment is hardly more than an int anyway), removing the QMap (most likely suboptimal in this case) and managing the invalid combinations of flags (Quote: "Conflicting combinations of flags have undefined meanings.") but it is the principle that is important. And the fact it uniformly impacts a wide range of things in Qt.

To understend the problem should look at qnamespace.h file.
To reproduce Alignment's problem, you have to additionaly declare
macros

Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(TestEnums)

Example for namespaces:
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Test {
Q_NAMESPACE_EXPORT(Q_CORE_EXPORT)

enum TestEnum { a = 1, b = 2, c = 4, d = 8, e = 16, f = 32 };
Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(TestEnums, TestEnum)
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(TestEnums)
// Q_ENUM_NS(TestEnum) <<NOT NEED
Q_FLAG_NS(TestEnums)
}; // namespace Test
QT_END_NAMESPACE

Notice that with Q_ENUM(_NS) macros will display just "" (_NS needs for namespaces).
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS macros declares global operator|() for flags. That macros should be in namespace but outter of class.
Example for classes:
class Tesclass : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Tesclass(QWidget *parent = nullptr) {}
  enum TestEnum { a = 1, b = 2, c = 4, d = 8, e = 16, f = 32 };
  Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(TestEnums, TestEnum)
  Q_FLAG(TestEnums)
};
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(Tesclass::TestEnums)

For more details see also QFlags

The snippet I had created when editing the question, which seems to be what you are addressing, was only to prove QVariant::toString did not use QMetaEnum::valueToKeys. This is not the issue I was trying to get an answer for. What I was describing is about synonyms inside an enumeration and the string we can generate from QVariant::toString.

I removed the edit BTW, to avoid the confusion. Now the question is back to its original version.
